# Mysterious number 6174 [Kaprekar Theorem] in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

In 1949 the mathematician D. R. Kaprekar, devised a process now known as Kaprekar's operation. First choose a four digit number where the digits are not all the same (that is not 1111, 2222,...). Then rearrange the digits to get the largest and smallest numbers these digits can make. Finally, subtract the smallest number from the largest to get a new number, and carry on repeating the operation for each new number.

> Let's try it out, starting with the number 2005, the digits of last
>   year. The maximum number we can make with these digits is 5200, and
>   the minimum is 0025 or 25 (if one or more of the digits is zero, embed
>   these in the left hand side of the minimum number)

```
5200 - 0025 = 5175
7551 - 1557 = 5994
9954 - 4599 = 5355
5553 - 3555 = 1998
9981 - 1899 = 8082
8820 - 0288 = 8532
8532 - 2358 = 6174
```

Now Objective is verify this theorem & find the number of iteration take to reach 6174.

> **Can anyone give a better algorithm?**  Here is my code.

```
public int VerifyKaprekarTheorem(int m) {
    if (m <= 1000 || m > 9999) {
        return -1;
    }
    String orginal = String.valueOf(m);
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        int Max = Integer.parseInt(sortString(orginal, false));
        int Min = Integer.parseInt(sortString(orginal, true));
        count++;
        int diff = Max - Min;
        if (diff == 6174) {
            break;
        }
        orginal = String.valueOf(diff);
    }
    return count;
}

public static String sortString(String Source, boolean assendingOrder) {
    char[] original = String.valueOf(Source).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(original);
    if (assendingOrder) {
        return new String(original);
    }
    char[] dessending = new char[original.length];
    for (int i = original.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        dessending[i] = original[(original.length - 1) - i];
    }
    return new String(dessending);
}
```

> and testcase

```
public void testCase01() {
    int actual = VerifyKaprekarTheorem(4321);   
    assertEquals(3, actual);
}
```

Comment: more suitable for codereview

Comment: No need to do integer to string then sort & again string to integer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat well, with a statement like this _Can anyone give a better algorithm?_ it's not suitable for CR either. CR is not _gimie teh code_.

Comment: @t3chb0t Point taken.

Comment: what do you mean by better algorithm? time/space complexity, code size, optimization ? You can get rid of the strings, add memoization etc ... My try in C++ took ~0.55ms on my setup (whole 4 digit range not just single number of coarse)... Without knowing what you want to improve is hard to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change Integer to String then char array than sorting again Integer conversion.

```
public int VerifyKaprekarTheorem(int m) {
    if (m <= 1000 || m > 9999) {
        return -1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        int Max = largestNumber(m);
        int Min = smallestNumber(m);
        count++;
        m = Max - Min;
        if (m == 6174) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
private static int largestNumber(int input) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for (int i = input; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        numbers[i % 10]++;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; counter += numbers[i++]) {
        result += (int) ((Math.pow(10, numbers[i]) * i - 1) / 9) * Math.pow(10, counter);
    }
    return result;
}

private static int smallestNumber(int input) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for (int i = input; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        numbers[i % 10]++;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; counter += numbers[i--]) {
        result += (int) ((Math.pow(10, numbers[i]) * i - 1) / 9) * Math.pow(10, counter);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Funny you should comment `No need to do integer to string then sort & again string to integer` to go on presenting _exactly_ that. The most intriguing part is the method name: what is the story behind `Kabuleke`?

Comment: modified code!!

Comment: Uncommented as the code is, I see conversion to decimal and back to binary - once little endian, once big endian. What I can't see is how this generates smallest and biggest: please try and comment your code such that the dense can see.